# Haskell recursion list of self growing lists

Tags: haskell, where-clause, tail-recursion

I found the following piece of code in Contract.hs line 147 [Pricing Financial Contracts with Haskell](https://github.com/AlexeyPirogov/PricingFinancialContractsWithHaskell):

```
konstSlices :: a -> [[a]]
konstSlices x = nextSlice [x]
    where nextSlice sl = sl : nextSlice (x:sl)
```

This produces a infinite list of lists:

```
konstSlices 100 = [[100],[100,100],[100,100,100],...]
```

I am not sure what is happening inside the where clause. If we just take 3 iterations what should be inside the nextSlice at this time

> `[100]:[100,100]:nextSlice (100 :[100,100])` ?

how the terminating: `[]` appears to pack the lists inside a list `[100]:[100,100]:[100,100,100]:[] = [[100],[100,100],[100,100,100]]`
the recursive construction is really hard to follow btw I am curious if there are tools allowing to follow such iterations and see how such values are build? Actually in such cases I am using a pen and a paper to get a grip on what is hapenning. Recursion lists are not the worst case btw.. (what bring me to this question was the analysis of the function `at t` (line 130) with the liftA2'ing stuff inside applicative functions which are build from other smaller functions or data constructor with function type, you rapidly see growing a big chunk of inter-related computations and you are totally lost - brain washed..)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a much simpler case for you

```
Prelude> let ones = 1 : ones
Prelude> take 3 ones
[1,1,1]
```

`ones` is defined to be an infinite list of `1`s.  There is no end, so there is no final empty list constructor.  `take n` initiates the generation of the first `n` elements, here with `n=3`.

Answer (score 1):

karakfa has a great illustration of what’s going on here, but I’ll expand a bit.

There isn’t any closing `]`.  A list is a data structure whose head is an item of data, and whose tail is a list.  Furthermore, objects in Haskell are **lazily evaluated**.

Let’s take another look at this example:

```
konstSlices :: a -> [[a]] 
konstSlices x = nextSlice [x]
    where nextSlice sl = sl : nextSlice (x:sl)
```

Lazy evaluation means that, if you try to use `konstSlices 100`, the program will only calculate as many items of the list as it needs to.  So, if you `take 1 (konstSlices 100)`, the program will compute

```
konstSlices 100 = [100]:
  nextSlice (100:[100]))
```

The tail of the list, everything after the `[100]:`, is stored as a **thunk**.  Its value hasn’t been computed yet.

What if you ask for `take 2 (konstSlices 100)`?  Then, the program needs to compute the thunk until it finds the second element.  That’s all it needs, so it will stop when it gets to,

```
    konstSlices 100 = [100]:
      [100,100]:
      (nextSlice (100:[100,100]))
```

And so on, for however many entries you need to compute.

There’s never anything corresponding to a closing bracket.  There doesn’t need to be.  The recursive definition of `konstSlices` never generates anything like one, just more thunks.  And that’s allowed.

On the other hand, if you try to take `length (konstSlices 100)`, the program will attempt to generate an infinite number of nodes, run out of memory, and crash.  If you tried to compute the entirety of a **circular** list, like `xs = 1:xs`, it wouldn’t need to allocate any new nodes, because it links back to the same ones, and it wouldn’t need to generate new stack frames, because it’s tail-recursive modulo cons, so it would go into an infinite loop.

Comment: So a way to understand this is to see that because each 'atomic' step of this computation is creating ( the `ones` in Karafka's illustration are in my case  [... stuff...] : [...stuff...] : etc...) a chain of lists so Haskell when evaluating is reasoning something like that " hey, I am asked to evaluate a bunch of things that are chained with `(:)` so because I am a smart guy I will give you a list of those things because it couldn't be nothing else". Great! Really.

Comment: @user3680029 Pretty much. Remember, a list is a data structure that is either the empty list `[]` or consists of a head and a tail. With lazy evaluation, the tail can be a thunk. A list terminates if its tail is `[]`, so `[1,2,3]` is the same as `1:2:3:[]`, but there’s no requirement that a list must terminate.

Comment: And, with lazy evaluation, an infinite list is not (necessarily) a bug, if the program only needs to evaluate a finite number of steps.

Answer (score 0):

the logic is very simple

```
konstSlices :: a -> [[a]]
konstSlices x = nextSlice [x]
    where nextSlice sl = sl : nextSlice (x:sl)
```

if `x = 100` then `nextSlice` will return `[100]` then it will recursive get first element and append it to the previous  list `nextSlice (x:sl)` in this case `sl` will grow with each call  , sorted by list index

```
0 -> [100] = [100]
1 -> [100,100] = nextSlice (100:[100])
2 -> [100 ,100,100] = nextSlice (100:[100 ,100])
3 -> [100 ,100 , 100,100] = nextSlice (100:[100 , 100,100])
```

and process will continue , 
`x:sl` the first element of `sl` list is `x`.
and every `nextSlice` call will return a list. `sl:sl:sl` ...

> same as this one where `acc = 1`

```
num = 100 : num
slice acc = take acc num :slice (acc+1)
```

Comment: The logic is not simple:-) I think that the problem comes also from the fact that when you try to 'test'/'inspect' such structure you have no tools and play on your paper, give some try in ghci where the only way to 'see' a list of lists is to add the `:[]` at the end and you 'infer' that the evaluation should also produce a `:[]` and finito you re trapped in a wrong reasoning... really tricky.

Comment: Actually you do have such a tool: https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/ghci.html#ghci-cmd-:print

Comment: may be you're right, may be I am groundlessly reluctant to gchi limiting myself to some :t and :info or :k to inspect my structures, also I never saw in any tutorial or blog somebody using ghci to show how to reason about what's happening under the hood. Will try. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is meant to be instructional.

The list with one value prepended is displayed every iteration so that you get

```
[100]
[100,100]
[100,100,100]
```

however many times you want it. Every list listed is a brand new list. Haskell builds a new list every iteration by prepending one value to the previous list. The use of a previous value in the next value is what recursive functions do. See below, the first example.

In an actual program, you might not be interested in the building of a list but only in the final result.

Haskell has functions that help you see your list as it is being built. The functions generalize primitive recursion and so can work with 90% of all recursive functions that you may need.

The functions are `foldl`/`foldr` and `scanl`/`scanr`. When you want to see your list being built use `scan?`. When you want just the final result use `fold?`.

You may only be interested in the construction as in the following to build a Fibonacci list up to 12.

```
scanl (\(a,b) x -> (a+b,a)) (1,0) [2..12]
```

[(1,0),(1,1),(2,1),(3,2),(5,3),(8,5),(13,8),(21,13),(34,21),(55,34),(89,55),(144,89)]

in which the previous two values are added to make the next first value and the previous first value becomes the next second value.

In your code with 3 iterations, you can see what happens to each, easily.

```
 take 3.konstSlices $ 100
```

[ [100],  [100,100],  [100,100,100] ]

```
scanl (\b a -> a : b) [] $ take 3 $ repeat 100
```

[ [], [100], [100,100], [100,100,100] ]

But this shows more. It has the initial null list value to which it prepends `100` to, for the next value.

If you want only the final result,

```
foldl (\b a -> a : b) [] $ take 3 $ repeat 100
```

[100,100,100]

It is exactly

```
100 : []        = [100]
100 : [100]     = [100,100]
100 : [100,100] = [100,100,100]
```